# Ошибка при использовании функции фильтра Qt

Tags: многопоточность, qt, c++

Следующий код

```
void BaseMode::slotCreatePreviousImageLoader()
{
    if (currentIndex_ > 0) {
        QFileInfoList::const_iterator begin = passageFileList_.begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < previousPosIndex_; ++i) {
            ++begin;
        }
        QFileInfoList::const_iterator end = begin;
        ++end;
        if (begin != end) {
            QFuture < QFileInfo > filterFuture = QtConcurrent::filtered(begin, end, &BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute);
        }
    }

    bool BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute(const QFileInfo & file) {
        return true;
    }
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

> `no match for call to '(QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<bool, BaseMode, const QFileInfo&>) (const QFileInfo&)'`
>
> `candidates are: T QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<T, C, U>::operator()(C&, U) [with T = bool, C = BaseMode, U = const QFileInfo&]`
>
> `In member function 'bool QtConcurrent::FilteredEachKernel<Iterator, KeepFunctor>::runIterations(Iterator, int, int, typename QtConcurrent::qValueType<Iterator>::value_type*) [with Iterator = QList<QFileInfo>::const_iterator, KeepFunctor = QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<bool, BaseMode, const QFileInfo&>]':`
>
> `instantiated from here`

Как исправить?

Update (мое решение)

Добавил функтор

```
struct loadWrapper {
    typedef QImage result_type;
    BaseMode *instance;
    loadWrapper(BaseMode *w): instance(w) {}
    QImage operator()(const QFileInfo& fileInfo) {
        return instance->loadImage(fileInfo);
     }
};
```

и использовал его так

```
loadWrapper wrap(this);
nextPixmapLoader_.setFuture(QtConcurrent::mapped(begin, end, wrap));
```

Вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: Включить мозг и не надеяться что на форуме вам напишут весь код без вашего  участия! Книжек почитайте...

Comment: Сразу видно, что @lirik90 ничего в этом не смыслит, если ты не понял, то автор просит исправить ошибку, а не писать за него программу.

Comment: вроде как можно исправить, использовав лямбда-функцию, но что то Qt Creator с ними не дружит. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Написание своего связывателя - дело полезное в учебных целях, ну а вообще лучше стараться использовать готовые решения, чтобы: во-первых сократить свой код и время на его написание, а во-вторых облегчить его чтение другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение

```
QFuture < QFileInfo > filterFuture = QtConcurrent::filtered(begin, end, &BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute);
```

компилироваться не будет, т.к. третий параметр функции `QtConcurrent::filtered()` [имеет сигнатуру функтора](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentfilter.html#filtered), а не указателя на функцию. Отличие между ними заключется в том, что [функтор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) - это объект, имеющий operator() и позволяющий использовать себя как функцию. Дело в том, что указатель на не статическую функцию-член класса задает смещение этой функции в таблице определения класса (т.е. в случае со статическими функциями это сработает), а нам нужно, чтобы была вызвана *функция конкретного экземпляра класса*, следовательно, нужно иметь адрес этого экземпляра + адрес функции.

В качестве решения можно либо использовать средства STL - связыватели (binder`s), - или средство библиотеки Boost: [bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html). Пример с boost:

```
QFuture < QFileInfo > filterFuture = QtConcurrent::filtered(begin, end, boost::bind(&BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute, this));
```

Comment: спасибо, но сделал по другому. Добавил функтор
struct loadWrapper {
    typedef QImage result_type;
    BaseMode *instance;
    loadWrapper(BaseMode *w): instance(w) {}
    QImage operator()(const QFileInfo& fileInfo) {
        return instance->loadImage(fileInfo);
    }
};

и использовал его так
loadWrapper wrap(this);
nextPixmapLoader_.setFuture(QtConcurrent::mapped(begin, end, wrap));

может пригодится кому. Ваш вариант не пробовал.